# Undefined variable "images" Matlab compiled code error

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, matlab-compiler

I received a Matlab jar function that includes an image processing algorithm, to be able to execute this jar file I installed the MCR library needed, I think with that I have all what I need in the MCR library, but I have this error:

```
Undefined variable "images" or class "images.internal.imlincombc".
Error in imlincomb (line 74)
Error in mat2gray (line 42)
```

Code Matlab:

```
scaled=mat2gray(projections(:,:,1));
```

The code matlab itself doesn't produce any error within matlab, but only if that function is compiled, and called from java code.

Do you have any idea why I have this error? Do I need also to install matlab with the image toolbox?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

These kinds of issues arises due to images toolbox. Your MATLAB probably does not have the Image Processing Toolbox (https://in.mathworks.com/products/image.html).

Try this command to verify

```
which -all images.internal.imlincombc
```

Comment: The OP said, *"The code matlab itself doesn't produce any error within matlab, but only if that function is compiled, and called from java code"*.